# Trying to assign value to nested list object and assign None if it doesn't exist

Tags: python, list, nested

I am modifying some code that was not created by me. It uses `requests.get` to get a webpage and load elements from it into the class object. Here is one statement used when defining the class object:

`self.img = item["images"][0]["url"]`.

This is an xml or json hierarchy, where you drill down to images, then 0, then pull the value for url. The problem I am having is on rare occasion, the key doesn't exist, so I get an error. For some of the other variables I am trying to assign I have been able to solve this with `.get`, such as in this example:

`self.prodcode = item.get("episodeNumber",None)`

That will get the value or assign `None` if it doesn't exist. I can't seem to get it to work with ones that are nested though, such as `self.img`. I tried:

`self.img = item.get('images', {}).get('0', {}).get('url')`

but I guess that only works with dictionaries and I believe this is a list because I get this error:
`AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'`

I'm somewhat new to lists and dictionaries, as I haven't done any extensive programming for about 20 years and the concepts were a bit different. How can I assign `self.img` with it being hierarchical and still account for the possibility that it might not exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to know if it failed, and don't care exactly what dimension of lookup caused it to fail, you could just wrap it in a try:

```
try:  # Try to reach the path
    self.img = item["images"][0]["url"]

# But in the exceptional circumstance that the lookup fails
# Handle that failure. 
except (KeyError, IndexError) as e:
    print("The exact path couldn't be reached:", e)
```

Comment: I just need the value, if it exists. If not, I don't care. I wasn't sure if I could do a `try`. I thought I got an error trying that previously but maybe I am thinking of something else. Or maybe I did it wrong. I'll give it a shot but I was hoping for a one-liner similar to `.get`, just to make things look cleaner as I might have to do this with a number of things and a lot of `try` statements looks messy to me. Thanks.

Comment: @user2328273 You could wrap a `try` in a function to easily create your own version of `get`.